# Swtich case issue in C language

Tags: c, switch-statement

I am making a mini project i c with the help of nested switch statement in my code **Error** is in **15th line** of the code,here **%c** is not working but **%s** is working,please help me to solve this query and tell me how to run this code with the use of **%c** here is my code:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
int a,b,c,ch;
char choice;
clrscr();
printf("1.Calculator\n2.Convrter\n\n");
printf("Enter your choice : ");
scanf("%d",&ch);
switch(ch)
{
    case 1:printf("1.Addition(A)\n2.Subtraction(S)\n3.Multiplication(M)\n4.Division(D)\n5.Module(P)\n\n");
    printf("Enter your choice : ");
    **scanf("%c",&choice);**
    switch(choice)
    {
    case 'A':printf("Provide the value of a : ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Provide the value of b : ");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    printf("\n");c=a+b;
    printf("%d",c);
    break;
    case 'S':printf("Provide the value of a : ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Provide the value of b : ");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    printf("\n");c=a-b;
    printf("%d",c);
    break;
    case 'M':printf("Provide the value of a : ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Provide the value of b : ");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    printf("\n");c=a*b;
    printf("%d",c);
    break;
    case 'D':printf("Provide the value of a : ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Provide the value of b : ");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    printf("\n");c=a/b;
    printf("%d",c);
    break;
    case 'P':printf("Provide the value of a : ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Provide the value of b : ");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    printf("\n");c=a%b;
    printf("%d",c);
    break;
    default:printf("Invalid Input");
    }
    break;
}
getch();
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"?  "Not working" is not a useful problem description.

Comment: Do basic debugging. Use a debugger to see exactly what the value of your variables are after each line of code. Or even just use basic debug print statements. It may be more obvious once you see the actual value of the `choice` variable.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add `getchar();` before
`scanf()`

because you will take `\n` as char choice
so one `getchar` will solve your problem

```
    case 1:printf("1.Addition(A)\n2.Subtraction(S)\n3.Multiplication(M)\n4.Division(D)\n5.Module(P)\n\n");
        printf("Enter your choice : ");
        getchar();
        scanf("%c", &choice); 
            switch (choice)
```

`%s` will work because it takes more than one char.
or you can:

```
1:printf("1.Addition(A)\n2.Subtraction(S)\n3.Multiplication(M)\n4.Division(D)\n5.Module(P)\n\n");
        printf("Enter your choice : ");
        scanf(" %c", &choice); //add space before %c
            switch (choice)
```

as H.S. said in comment.

Comment: A space before `%c` will be sufficient, like this - `scanf(" %c", &choice);`. No need to call `getchar()` before `scant()`.

Answer (score 0):

The previous call to `scanf()`:

```
scanf("%d",&ch);
```

in Line 10, leaves the newline character (`\n`) made by the push to Enter/Return inside `stdin`.

This newline character is read on the second `scanf()` call since the `%c` format/conversion specifier does not ignore leading white space and also read/consumes non-printable characters.

Just insert white space before the conversion specifier `%c`:

```
scanf(" %c",&choice);
```

to catch that newline character or any leading white space.